# searching 2GB sql.gz file for frequently used word

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, grep, archive

I want to change slug x to slug y, it is so important and critical change.

There are ~ 150 tables with bunch of columns so Mysql search wouldn't be efficient. I tried to search from backup file. But I couldn't succeded with zgrep.

I would like to search 'x'|/x/ but not x-y or www.x.com it is actually simple regex but couldn't achieve with zgrep could you please give some advice how to use zgrep for this purpose ?

```
zgrep "'x'|/x/" daily_backup.sql.gz
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
zcat daily_backup.sql.gz| grep -E "'x'|/x/"
```

-E puts grep into 'extended regexp' so the alternation operator `|` works

Comment: Thank you its OK now, If anyone needs only count use -c flag, `zcat daily_backup.sql.gz| grep -c -E "'x'|/x/"`